# Markdown.NET incorrectly does not escape HTML-Tags

Tags: html, markdown

it seems that Markdown.NET does not escape the following:

```
<script>
```

which is kind of a problem...

Is there any other way of generating HTML from Markdown on the server with ASP.NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Markdown [explicitly allows HTML markup](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html) so: "... incorrectly does not escape ..." is not quite right.

Which means that you're on the hook for sanitizing it yourself. You could even use [Stack Overflow's HTML sanitizer](http://refactormycode.com/codes/333-sanitize-html) if you wanted to.